# Is there a way to setup WebStorm to execute Javascript/Protractor code in place using Evaluate Expression tool?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript, protractor, angular, intellij

I'm coming from a Java+Selenium environment, so maybe this is a mismatch of understanding that I'm having with Javascript/Angular/Protractor.  I used to use IntelliJ's IDEA IDE for automation testing. I could actively do live search and on the fly testing of ideas using IDEA's Evaluate Expression functionality.  I could actively look for elements on a page (searching using CSS selectors for instance) and do a click (or see what the text is), and if my test was in debug mode it would do the click on the page.

I was really hoping for a similar experience with WebStorm since it's IntelliJ's answer for Javascript development. I'm in the middle of debugging a Protractor UI test and I can't look at the result of a getText() without doing a `.then()` clause and a console.log in the `.then()` clause.  I feel like if I do `element.getText()` in the Evaluate Expression tool I should be able to see what that Promise will evaluate to without having to do a then clause that resolves the Promise. I understand there's stuff having to do with the asynchronous nature of Javascript that requires the resolution of the Promise, but I would think this super smart IDE would have resolution stuff built in. Is there a way to setup WebStorm to say 'hey, resolve this for me and let me see what happens!"? I would hope for getting the same behavior when I evaluate `element.click()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the closest thing to what you are asking about is ["Elementor" library](https://github.com/andresdominguez/elementor) and a [WebStorm plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7636-elementor):

- install `elementor`
- run `webdriver-manager start` local selenium server
- run `elementor https://yourUrlHere`
- install `Elementor` plugin in WebStorm

Now, you should be able to test your locators from inside the WebStorm or from the Chrome window opened by Elementor.

For example, this is what I can do now (see how the text value is resolved):

[image]

---

You can also use the available Protractor debugging tool. For instance, you can put `browser.enterRepl()` before a desired line and then test your locators and expressions in the command prompt. Also see:

- [Debugging in Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md)
- [What is the difference between browser.pause() and browser.enterRepl()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31413300/what-is-the-difference-between-browser-pause-and-browser-enterrepl)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I was searching for it backwards, trying things like "webstorm evalutor protractor" didn't bring up any of this.  Thanks so much for the extended explanation.